# How to include "=" in AngularJs $http.get params?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, typescript, get

I am trying to include an equals sign in an AngularJs $http.get params section. Here is the relevant code:

```
let eventsRequest = this.$http.get(EVENTS_ENDPOINT, {
        params: {
            type: type,
            filter: 'eventId=' + eventId
        }
    });
```

Essentially, I want this to serialize to:

```
?type=my_type&filter=eventId=this_event_id
```

However, when I run the following code the "=" is replaces with %3d. I tried escaping with a "/", but it didn't work. I also tried looking through the angular documentation, but couldn't find anything. Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: This is expected behavior. Your server(api) should be able to decode the uri component. when you use `params` angular internally uses `encodeURIComponent` on the params, you could also try not to use `params` in this case, instead construct the query manually i.e `this.$http.get(EVENTS_ENDPOINT + ['?type=', type, '&filter=', 'eventId=' , eventId].join(""));` However it depends on how your server is going to read it.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually the expected behavior when passing a reserved character (=) as a query parameter value. Your browser [URL encodes](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_url_encoding.htm) those characters so the query parameters can be parsed on the receiving end (your server).

You'll have to use a different mechanism to pass specific filters or deserialize the 'equals' sign on your server.

Another possible way to define your URL scheme:

```
?type=my_type&filterEventId=this_event_id&filterLocationId=this_location_id
```

Comment: Yeah, I knew it was the expected behavior, I was just hoping there was a way around this for this one case. Thanks!